# How to sent data angular 2 into other component if I use <router-outlet>?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have 2 components: **Parent** and **Child**. In view of  **Parent** component I have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` for show **Child** component after routing.(/parent and /parent/child)
I get data from other server when user on **Parent**, and save it in **data** variable. I want to use this data in **Child** component after routing.
I cant to find working answer, can anyone to help me?

Answer (score 3):

Use a service for that purpose:

```
@Component({
...
})
ParentComponents {
  private data;
  contructor(private myData: SharedService ){
     myData.getData().subscribe((data) =>  this.data= data);
  }
}

import {SharedService } from '...';

@Component({
...
})
export class ChildComponent{
  private data;
  contructor(private myData: SharedService ){
     myData.getData().subscribe((data) =>  this.data= data);
  }

}
```

Create a service to use it like Observable

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  private _sharedDataSource = new BehaviorSubject<MyModel>(<MyModel>{});
  sharedData$ = this._sharedDataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  getData() {
    return this.sharedData$;
  }

  updateSharedData(data: MyModel) {
     this._sharedDataSource.next(data);
  }

}
```

Then you can use the `updateSharedData` method to update the data, from any place in your Application.

Comment: If the data is bound ... is this BehaviorSubject really needed here?

Comment: It is up to you and from the data you want to share, but for me the best solution would be share data via Service.

Comment: Yes, I agree that a service is often the best choice. That was not my question. I often share data with a service, but never use BehaviorSubject in my service. If the data is bound, the updates are automatically populated to anyone sharing that data. So I was curious about the purpose of the BehaviorSubject in your service.

Comment: It's just an exmaple how you can share data and change/update it over time. It was not mentioned in the question if the data will be bound or it will change over time. BehaviorSubject - Represents a value that changes over time. Observers can subscribe to the subject to receive the last (or initial) value and all subsequent notifications. If you are looking for BehaviorSubject without initial value.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a parent and child, another option is to use a shared resolver.

Build a resolver to get the data, then get the resolver data from both the parent and the child.

Here is the route definition:

```
  {
    path: ':id/edit',   <-- parent
    component: ProductEditComponent,
    resolve: { product: ProductResolver },
    children: [         <-- children
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'info',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'info',
        component: ProductEditInfoComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'tags',
        component: ProductEditTagsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

And here is the code to get this resolver data:

```
// In the parent
ngOnInit(): void {
    // Watch for changes to the resolve data
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
         this.onProductRetrieved(data['product']);
    });
}

// In the child
ngOnInit(): void {
    // Watch for changes to the resolve data
    this.route.parent.data.subscribe(data => {
         this.onProductRetrieved(data['product']);
    });
}
```

I have a complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing in the APM-Final folder. This is part of my Angular Routing course on Pluralsight: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing/table-of-contents